# ASP.NET Friendly URLs - redirect 'default' to root of site

Tags: asp.net

I am using "Friendly URL's" and they work great.

However - I don't want the page 'default.aspx' to redirect to 'default' - because that gives me duplicate content (on root and /default) - and also because it's ugly.

How can I redirect site.com/default and site.com/default.aspx to site.com?

I have tried adding this line to the RouteConfig.cs file above where FriendlyURL's are registered

```
// Attempt to route 'default' to root
routes.MapPageRoute("default", "default.aspx", "~/");

// Enable Friendly URLs
var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

However this appears to have no effect.

As the page exists I presume anything under Friendly URLs will be ignored.

I have seen various really old articles on this but none appear to solve it.

Is there best practice for this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of mapping the routes like that, have you tried just updating all links (and redirects) on your site that go to the home page to go to `~/` instead of `~/Default.aspx` or `~/default`?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to introduce defualt.aspx page as home page of your site. 
You should try this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "", "~/Default.aspx");
```

Comment: No sorry I wasn't clear.

I would like mysite.com/default.aspx - to redirect to mysite.com